# Dependency property binding doesnt work

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property of type bool

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SControlParamsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SControlParams",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(PView),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnShowHideSControlChanged)
            );
```

and the property:

```
public bool SControlParams 
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SControlParamsProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SControlParamsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

and the binding

```
var binding = new Binding("SControlParams");
this.SetBinding(SControlParamsProperty, binding);
```

and the property in the VM:

```
bool _sControlParams = false;
    public bool SControlParams
    {
        get { return _sControlParams; }
        set
        {
            _sControlParams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SControlParams");
        }
    }
```

And it works great!

But when I change the Property in VM, the binding works and OnShowHideSControlChanged called in the view.

But,
When I only change the type of the property to be MyType :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SControlParamsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SControlParams",
            typeof(MyType ),
            typeof(PView),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnShowHideSControlChanged)
            );
public MyType SControlParams 
    {
        get { return (MyType)GetValue(SControlParamsProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SControlParamsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

and in the VM :

```
MyType _sControlParams = ...;
    public MyType SControlParams
    {
        get { return _sControlParams; }
        set
        {
            _sControlParams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SControlParams");
        }
    }
```

The handler OnShowHideSControlChanged doesn't called anymore..

What could be a problem ?
Thanks

Comment: How do you change your property?

Comment: I tried your code and it works even if I change bool with MyType. Can you post the whole code, plese?

Comment: Now it works ! 
When I change the _sControlParams to be a new object each time it works.
When it is the same object, but I only change one of its properties it does not work.
I dont know why...

Comment: That's the way it should work. When you change any property value of an object, the object reference itself doesn't change. You should read about object references in C# and passing parameters by value / by reference.